# Any Solution for this I have already Added autoReconnect = true?

Tags: java, mysql, micronaut, sql2o

{
    "message": "Internal Server Error: Database error: The last packet successfully received from the server was 89,722,963 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 89,722,964 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem."
}

Comment: The answer is in the message: "You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity..."  Read the MySQL documentation for how to go about doing this...Oh, and learn to test your code after you've written 5 to 10 lines of code.  If you wait until you've written hundreds or thousands of lines, you'll take a lot longer to find the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask